# In what way was Boba Fett "double-crossed"?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett, the-book-of-boba-fett

In *The Book of Boba Fett*'s Episode 4: The Gathering Storm, Boba and Fennec have this exchange:

> **Fennec:** What's next for you?
>  **Boba:** I'm gonna find my armor. Then I'm gonna kill that bloated pig who double-crossed me. Take his throne.
>  **Fennec:** You wanna head a Gotra?
>  **Boba:** Why not?

I couldn't quite make sense of this, since presumably he's talking about

> Bib Fortuna, but it's not clear how or whether Bib and Boba had interacted before then.

Throughout his appearance in *Return of the Jedi*, Boba is taking orders from Jabba, and only falls into the Sarlacc because of his own decision to fly into the fray and get whacked with a stick by Han.

Is this in reference to some event that has been shown, an event that hasn't yet been shown, or is it just Boba's opinionated view of the events of *Return of the Jedi*?

Comment: since Boba Fett was still hanging around Jabba during RotJ, it's *possible* that Jabba didn't pay him the full bounty. Fett says of Solo to Vader in ESB: "He's no good to me dead." - when Fett brings Han to Jabba, he (Solo) isn't 'technically' dead, but he's not really alive for Jabba to gloat over and punish like he may have wanted to do. So, perhaps he paid Fett only a partial bounty or none at all and Fett was hanging around trying to get his full credits? Maybe that could be the double-cross he speaks of? Or maybe he means that he was left to die in the Sarlaac (not knowing Jabba died)

Comment: @ NKCampbell I don't think that's the case, Leia is able to release him pretty easily. It seems like Jabba made the choice to keep him encased.

Comment: He is certainly aware that Jabba is dead. He and Fennec discuss Fortuna taking over after Jabba's death prior to this interaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing that I can think of is the events of the *War of the Bounty Hunters* comic event, which occur shortly after *Empire*, before Han Solo is delivered to Jabba. In it, Solo's body is temporarily stolen from Fett. Jabba assumes that Fett sold it to someone else and puts a hit on him. For this, Fett is clearly annoyed at Jabba, and Bib Fortuna by-proxy.

[image: War of the Bounty Hunters Issue 1]

It eventually gets resolved, but Fett probably maintained a grudge over it. Throughout *The Book of Boba Fett*, Fett expresses disdain for the ruling style of Jabba and figures like him. In particular, he sets out to provide what Jabba didn't: loyalty.

> I can offer you something no client ever has... Loyalty.

The comic incident is the most obvious example of Jabba (and Fortuna) being disloyal to Fett, so I wouldn't be surprised if this is what he was referring to.